# Setting some Parse.User property on beforeSave when running on Heroku

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Can you edit data in beforeSave callback and if yes, how?

Looking at various docs, it seem like this code should work (using `"_User"` or `Parse.User`) and I can see `Ran beforeSave on a User` and `new user!` in my logs but the key `aaa` is still empty..

I've tried to add `user.save()` after `user.set` but still no luck. 
Any idea?

```js
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("_User", function(request, response) {
  console.log('Ran beforeSave on a User');
  var user = request.object;
  if(user.existed()) {
    response.success(); 
  } else {
    console.log('new user!');
    user.set('aaa', 'xxx');
    response.success();
  }
});
```

**EDIT 2015/12/03**: Maybe critical info, this code is running on **heroku**. http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-heroku-parse/

**EDIT 2015/12/05**: It seem to be a bug with Heroku / Parse integration. beforeSave hook are called but doesn't seem to allow you to edit the request.object..

**EDIT 2015/12/07**: I've created an issue on the `CloudCode-Express` repo https://github.com/ParsePlatform/CloudCode-Express/issues/6

Comment: You're trying to set value to user variable which is local. Try this : `request.object.set('aaa','xxx');`

Comment: We're using the same `user.set()` function in our code and it works, even if using a local variable. We've had some problems with `existed()`, however, and for our use case we can go with `if (!user.get('aaa')) {}` instead.

Comment: I've tried by referencing the `request.object` directly before refactoring a bit.. no luck...

Comment: I'm having the same problem, also running beforeSave on heroku. I think it's a bug in the Parse webhook implementation, as it did work when this was implemented directly in Parse Cloud Code. Might have to put the beforeSave back on the Parse server and not heroku until they fix it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Webhooks, you need to pass back the changed object:

`response.success(object);`

Comment: Time to update the doc, https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-modifying-objects-on-save :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to use `isNew()` method:

```js
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
  console.log('Ran beforeSave on a User');

  if(!request.object.isNew()) {
    response.success(); 
  } else {
    console.log('new user!');
    request.object.set('aaa', 'xxx');
    response.success();
  }
});
```

Comment: As I said, the log show `new user!` so the block is executed.. not sure it will give me more... but thx..

Comment: Is that the whole function ? What do you see in the log as Input and Result ?

Comment: yep.. I see 'Ran beforeSave on a User' && 'new user!'

Comment: can you post those two lines here ? the ones that start with Input and Result

Comment: 2015-12-03T09:39:47.487912+00:00 app[web.1]: Ran beforeSave on a User
2015-12-03T09:39:47.487982+00:00 app[web.1]: new user!

Comment: No no, find these two lines in your log `Input: {"original":null,"update": ...` and `Result: Update changed to:....`

Comment: Nothing like this in my logs.. (using `heroku logs`)?

Comment: it seem to be related to heroku.. will try to move this code back to cloud code..